# Like button not creating the Facebook Page on external URLs

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

Since around June 19th the pages I 'Like' in my site (which generate all the metadata automatically) are no longer creating the respective Facebook Page where one could 'Build Traffic' to the page, monitor likes, comments, etc. The previous pages do have the reference, but pages created and liked from then on are not!

Also, the pages are not showing on the Pages I Like section of www.facebook.com/pages . If I go there and change to the pages I have liked I see only the pages up until that day, and newer pages on other sites, but no longer the pages I liked on my own site! The weird thing is that if I navigate to the page itself, I can see myself as a 'liker' of the page.

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Go to a page inside my Web Page : http://rafaelpolit.com/inicio/index.php?sid=14&gim=240&ln=2
2. Like the Web Page
3. Go to your www.facebook.com/pages and navigate to Pages I like
4. The page does not show there.

Comment: Edit June 29: This has been recognized as a bug by FaceBook developers all over and the staff is 'looking into it', with priority 'high' assigned to the issue.  Hopefully it will get resolved soon.

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing it via this link:

https://www.facebook.com/pages/OGTitle/OGObjectID

Comment: Thanks, that would be fantastic if I only knew the Object ID!  I have found that there are two different IDs for each page.  One is that ID you talk about, the other is the ID for the Insights. The one for the insights I am able to fetch, the other one though, I cannot even learn which ID it is!

Comment: Did your the URL through the linter?  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug.  That will return the object id.  When I use the url you reference above it returns this 10150872030695855 as the object id.

Comment: Thank you... yes, I know, but that ID works for insights and probably other stuff... but it DOES NOT work for administering the facebook page.  Is there any other way?  Thanks.

Comment: Your Admin ID or an App ID is included in the OG tags?  It works for my objects.  I would open a bug with Facebook.